# IIFE, modules and JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, iife

I'm trying to understand some code :

```
(function (exports) {

 exports.myProperty = "azerty";

 console.log(exports)

}((this.myModule = this.myModule || {})));
```

What I understood from this code :

1) I'm executing an IIFE and "this" represents Window (the global object).

2) Since Window doesn't have a myModule property, this.myModule = this.myModule adds a new property to Window object and this property is undefined.

3) (this.myModule=this.myModule) || {} returns {} so exports equals {} (empty object)

4) I'm adding a property "myProperty" to export object so export = {myProerty: "azerty"}

What I don't understand : after executing this code, when I console.log(window), I can see that :

[image]

Window object has a property myModule equals to the exports object. How the relation between myModule and {myProperty: "azerty"} has been resolved ?
I can't understand this part.

Comment: `this.myModule = this.myModule || {}` is `this.myModule = (this.myModule || {})`, not `(this.myModule = this.myModule) || {}`.

Comment: Objects are reference-type values and are mutable. The object that is passed as `exports` is also assigned to `this.myModule` in `this.myModule = this.myModule || {}`.

Comment: @Ry : thank you. I just realized that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your #3 is wrong. The parenthesis in the original code are like this:

```
(this.myModule=this.myModule || {})
```

and it's evaluated like this:

```
this.myModule = (this.myModule || {})
```

If a new empty object is created, it is assigned to `this.module` right away, before being assigned to `exports` via the function argument. Thus `window.myModule` and `exports` are both references to the same object.

Comment: Yes, like Ry said earlier you're right. Didn't see that